# cannot get url query params to appear?

Tags: angular

I am trying to make a link set a query string param in the url...

In my view, I am doing:

```
<a (click)="selectPage(123)">123</a>
```

and in my component:

```
selectPage(page: number) {
  this.router.navigate([], { relativeTo: this.route, queryParams: { 'page': page}, queryParamsHandling: 'merge', skipLocationChange: true});
}
```

I click the link, the selectPage function fires, but the url in the browser does not have a page parameter show up..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to omit `skipLocationChange` property, then it would work.